# Connect Redis which is installed on same network's different machine's VMWare's ubuntu

Tags: networking

I have a laptop (windows OS) which is connected to a wifi network.

On same wifi network, there is another PC (Windows OS). In that PC, I have ubuntu installed inside VMWare. And in that ubuntu, I have installed Redis.

How do I access that PC's VMware's Ubuntu's Redis from my laptop?

Comment: I think this question fits better on superuser

Answer (score 1):

- Set VMware's network adaptor to bridged mode.
- Set a fixed IP address on the Ubuntu VM.
- VNC into the Ubuntu machine.